# node.getProperty(byteArrayProperty) returns String and not a byte[] in case of RestGraphDatabase

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

We are facing an issue with the scenario below.

1. We have a requirement where we need to store `byte[]` in a graph node. We do the same using `node.setProperty("name", byte[]);`. The issue is when we try to retrieve this `byte[]` using `node.getProperty("name")`.
2. The above `getProperty(..)` call works fine when we use the `EmbeddedGraphDatabase` class. As expected, in this case, a `byte[]` is returned. But, if we use a `RestGraphDatabase` class instance, a `String` (instead of `byte[]`) gets returned and is not equivalent to what we stored.

Note: the variable node in the above context could either be an instance of `Node` or `RestNode`.

Help us in this regard. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uhh,
that is probably a limitation of JSON as the transport format. Maybe you could ask for others having this issue on the mailing list, or file an issue at https://github.com/neo4j/community/issues ?